# Can I travel to Greece using my French visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, france, greece

Can I travel to Greece using my French Schengen visa? I went to France for 4 days but I really want to go to Greece for 10 days I suppose I can visit France a few more times to make up the days to 10. I'm worried, however, that there will be problems at the Greek border.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in comments that the visa you have is a 1-year multiple entry visa, and that you have already completed the trip to France you originally applied for.

In that case, you should have no problems at all. With a **multiple-entry** visa, after it has has been used for the trip that it was originally issued for, it is *valid for subsequent trips to anywhere in the Schengen area* without further ado.

The reason why getting a visa from one Schengen country and using it for a different one can be problematic is that it raises an inference that you were *lying* to the issuing country when you said you were planning a trip with it as a main destination. But in your case, then you did complete the trip to France as planned, there is no issue of telling them something that turned out not to be true.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I Can finally stop researching the issue. Hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can travel to Greece using the French Schengen visa. Actually I travel the same route last year. First I arrived Paris for 2 days, then went to Rome for 3 days... the last station is Athens and Santorini. 
According Schengen Agreement, I must spend the longest time in French, but it seems no border officers care about that, so I didn't have any problems entering and leaving the Greek border.

Comment: There are posts on this site from users who *did* get caught having spent the majority of their trip in a country other than the issuer of their visa and were denied subsequent visas. Just because you got away with it does not mean it is a safe or recommended course of action.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I actually did stick to my original itinerary and went to France for 4 days last month, but because I got a one year multiple entry visa I really want to use it to travel around greece. So because I will spend more time in Greece than in France, I could then travel to France a few more times like say in winter as my visa doesn't expire until next April. So when I applied for the visa, Greece wasn't on my plans it's a last minute thing. I should also mention I'll be traveling with my husband who is British.

Comment: Any answers would be appreciated please, regarding making a second but longer trip to Greece